# Clarification is needed on the use of the Time class

Tags: time, toit

The *Time* class allows to get the standard time parameters up to sec:

```
main :
  time := Time.now.local
  print "Time: $(%02d time.h):$(%02d time.m):$(%02d time.s) $(time.ns)"
  print "Date: $(%04d time.year)-$(%02d time.month)-$(%02d time.day)"
```

*Out:*

```
Time: 07:43:10 96212801
Date: 2021-04-18
```

There is also a *time.ns* parameter, which apparently allows to get additional time resolutions in *micro* & *milli* seconds as well. Apparently it can be done like this:

```
main :
  time := Time.now.local
  ms := time.ns / Duration.NANOSECONDS_PER_MILLISECOND
  us := time.ns / Duration.NANOSECONDS_PER_MICROSECOND
  print "Time: $(%02d time.h):$(%02d time.m):$(%02d time.s) $(ms) $(us)"
```

*Out:*

```
Time: 13:13:00 721 721000
```

However, I still have doubts. Could you suggest the correct solution?
Thanks in advance, MK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct.

The `Time.now.local` returns a `TimeInfo` class (https://libs.toit.io/core/time/class-TimeInfo) which only has `ns` but no `ms` or `us`.

You are correctly computing the value for the `ms` and `us`:

```
ms := time.ns / Duration.NANOSECONDS_PER_MILLISECOND
us := time.ns / Duration.NANOSECONDS_PER_MICROSECOND
```

You could just append either to the output of stringify to make it more precise:

```
more_precise_ms := "Time: $(%02d time.h):$(%02d time.m):$(%02d time.s).$(%03d ms)
more_precise_us := "Time: $(%02d time.h):$(%02d time.m):$(%02d time.s).$(%06d ns)
```

The first would yield: `Time: 13:13:00.721` and the second: `Time: 13:13:00.721000`.

If you wanted to present the milliseconds and nanoseconds separately, you would want to drop the milliseconds from the microseconds part:

```
ms := time.ns / Duration.NANOSECONDS_PER_MILLISECOND
remaining_ns := time.ns % Duration.NANOSECONDS_PER_MILLISECOND
us := remaining_ns / Duration.NANOSECONDS_PER_MICROSECOND
```

You could then use this to print as follows:

```
print "Time: $(%02d time.h):$(%02d time.m):$(%02d time.s) $(%03d ms)ms $(%03d us)us"
```

Resulting in: `Time: 13:13:00 721ms 000us`